# Why does rails add "order_by id" to all queries? Which ends up breaking Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The following rails code:

```
class User < MyModel
  def top?
    data = self.answers.select("sum(up_votes) total_up_votes").first
    return (data.total_up_votes.present? && data.total_up_votes >= 10)
  end
end
```

Generates the following query (note the **order_by** added by Rails):

```
SELECT
   sum(up_votes) total_up_votes 
FROM
   "answers" 
WHERE
   "answers"."user_id" = 100
ORDER BY
   "answers"."id" ASC
```

This throws an error in Postgres:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "answers.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Is rails' database abstraction only made with MySQL in mind?

Answer (score 2):

No, the 'order by id' is added to ensure `.first` always returns the same result.  Without an ORDER BY clause, the result is not guaranteed to be the same under the SQL spec.

For your case, you should use `.sum()` instead of `.select()` to do this more simply:

```
def top?
  self.answers.sum(:up_votes) >= 10
end
```

Comment: Is is possible to add a where clause to this as well to limit by date? i.e. `self.answers.sum(:up_votes).where('created_at between ? and ?', 1.week.ago, Time.now) >= 10`

Comment: Rails doesn't recognize the where clause and gives the error `undefined method `where' for 388:Fixnum`

Comment: @user3188544 Just read this url - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first

Comment: @ArupRakshit Thanks for the link. I understood the problem with using `first` -- the question in my previous comment was about using a where clause with `sum()`

Comment: where(created_ad: 1.week.ago..Time.now)

Comment: @user3188544 - put the `.where()` clause before calling `.sum()`: `self.answers.where(created_at: (1.week.ago, Time.now)).sum(:up_votes)`.  Calling `sum` executes the query and returns a Fixnum, calling `where` keeps the query chain intact.

Answer (score 0):

You used `#first` method at the end. That's the reason.

```
self.answers.select("sum(up_votes) total_up_votes").first # <~~~
```

> Model.first finds the first record ordered by the primary key

Look at the clause

```
ORDER BY
   "answers"."id" ASC  # this is the primary key of your table ansers.
```

Check the documentation of [`1.1.3 first`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) or [`#first`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first) .